# Scale down image to fit into div, but never scale up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several images with very varying dimensions.
Some images may be as small as 50x100 and others as big as 4000x4000.

I want to show these images in their original size (never bigger), or scaled down to just fit inside the browser window.

Using the background image property I have gotten the images to always fit inside the browser, but I can't stop them from up-scaling if the browser is bigger than the image:

```
 <div class="slide-pane" style="background-image: url(<insert url to image here>);"></div>

.slide-pane {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:auto;
    position: absolute;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

I have found these Javascript/Jquery solutions:

- https://github.com/gutierrezalex/photo-resize
- [How to resize an image to fit in the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169666/how-to-resize-an-image-to-fit-in-the-browser-window)

But I'm hoping there are some CSS only solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
max-height:100%;
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
```

Apply that to an `img` not an elements background image. Background images don't have full browser support for max width height. You could use background-size set to 100% 100% but I'd recommend using an `img` for better css control and accessibility.

Comment: I also add `object-fit: contain` for some use cases

Answer (score 1):

If they’re content images (and not there for style) then you’re better off using an `<img>` element in the page. If you do that then you can give it `img { max-width: 100%; }` in your CSS. This has the added benefit of working in IE8 (unlike `background-size`).