# How do I fit svg to html width and height?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to create a page contains only one `svg` element that fit width and height and has maximum possible scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Related questions

[How can I make an svg scale with its parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6169666)

[How to resize an image to fit in the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19484707)

didn't work, but combination of proposed methods solved the problem.

1) replace `width="A" height="B"` in opening `<svg ...>` tag to `viewBox="0 0 A B" max-width="100%" width="auto" max-height="100vh" height="auto"`.

Now it nearly works But not very accurate because browser automatically adds `margin: 8` to `body`'s style (even if there is not `<body>` tag in `.html` file). So

2) add `<style> body { margin: 0 } </style>`

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I used this CSS to fit a background image to width and height and it scales down accordingly to the browser.

```
html { 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

You can set your SVG in a DIV and add a class to it, then you simply use the above CSS to scale the DIV's content.

Answer (score 0):

put your image in a div, and apply these css rules:

```
div{
  height:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
svg{
  height:100%;
  width:100%
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that just crops the svg

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you guys. Check the link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-irfyqi)

```
   html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .svg-cont {
      width: 100vh;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .svg-cont > svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```