# Resizing images to fit the screen

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know how to auto resize an image depending on the screen size of the device.

My image is too big and make my web page extend with it...

```css
.gris {
  height: 100%;
  left: 20%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
}
```

```html
<div class="gris">
  <img src="https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/image-noir-png.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize an image to fit in the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169666/how-to-resize-an-image-to-fit-in-the-browser-window)

Comment: I made you a snippet. Your transparency makes the image invisible. Please change the html and image to a [mcve] - you can get images at lorempixel or placeholder.com

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
.gris img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

This will fill up the width, and keep the aspect ratio. However make sure you don't put small images, because in that case it will scale up (stretch it up). In that case you may need this:

```
.gris img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

And don't set the width!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried targeting the img itself? Also, you have a `position: absolute` and `left: 20%` so that will through it off when resizing.

```
.gris img {
  width: 100%;
}
```