# How to resize an image to fit the remaining window below a container?

Tags: javascript, css

I've read through [How to resize an image to fit in the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169666/how-to-resize-an-image-to-fit-in-the-browser-window)
but it doesn't really fit my need. All there is written for the image to fill the entire browser window. But I want a container of varying height above the image. And a fixed height section below.

JavaScript can get the height of the container. I found:

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('topsection').offsetHeight;
```

Andrew Beals's solution on that page looks like a start, but how to subtract the container height, and say 2em for under? I know no JavaScript, so I'd much appreciate some help.

Comment: I think I do not understand your question, could you put an example HTML? Do you need JS? Wouldn't CSS Grid Layoud? https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: To understand what I am looking for, one has to first fully understand what is being done on that page. Then, where that page has the image covering the entire window, I want it to fill the space below a top section and above a footer. So the height calculation, instead of being the window height, has to be that height, less the height of the top section and footer.