# Size of two images + top bar = Viewport size

Tags: html, css

Condition 1: A 46px top bar
Condition 2: 1 photo at the top and the other at the bottom
I have tried the methods listed on [How to resize an image to fit in the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169666/how-to-resize-an-image-to-fit-in-the-browser-window), but there is still slightly taller than the viewport. I have to scroll down to see the lower part of the photo.
How can I make it fit perfectly of the viewport? Do the size of the photos matter?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

## using CSS GRID

The Idea is simple (code snippet below) but I will explain it well here so everyone can understand!

### new answer

I used the `calc();` function in CSS (is for doing dynamic calculations in your CSS)

I use this CSS VARIABLE for setting the height of nav

```css
--nav-height: 46px;
```

so now for use, it write `height: var(--nav-height);` in your *nav* selector

---

if you want Two Images, One on top, and One on the bottom...

just write `display: grid;` in the parent element. in fact, the `grid` makes everything inside in a row. (that's simple)

### don't use `%` for this, instead, use:

- **`vh` for height** (is a metric equal to 1% of all height of the browser, no matter the parent width or height)
- **`vw` for width** (is a metric equal to 1% of all width of the browser, no matter the parent width or height)

with `vh` this layout it will be also **Responsive**

> Responsive = is work in all devices

normally if you want to set half-height for every image use `50vh`

> 50vh = 1/2 screen Height (half screen)

### but one problem...

your question is include also a nav in it...

I find a solution!

use this Formula:

```css
--img-height: calc(50vh - ((var(--nav-height)) / 2))
```

the idea is:

1. set the height to `half_Height`
2. and get the `NavHeight`
3. decrease the half of `NavHeight` for every Image (so the two image be equal)

###### in the end:

set the width of images with `auto`

```css
    width: auto;
```

with `auto` your image not be stretched wrong.

## the code

```css
* {
  --nav-height: 46px;
  --img-height: calc(50vh - ((var(--nav-height)) / 2))
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  height: var(--nav-height);
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
}

.container .image {
  height: var(--img-height);
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>my Awesome NavBar</nav>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="image" src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## previous answer

if you want a Two Element, One on top, and One on the bottom...

just write `display: grid;` in the parent element. in fact, the `grid` makes everything inside in a row. (that's simple)

### don't use `%` for this, instead, use:

- **`vh` for height** (is a metric equal to 1% of all height of the browser, no matter the parent width or height)
- **`vw` for width** (is a metric equal to 1% of all width of the browser, no matter the parent width or height)

#### so now set the height of `50vh` in the images

> 50vh = 1/2 screen Height (half screen)

with `vh` this layout it will be also **Responsive**

> Responsive = is work in all devices

### set the width of images with `auto`

```css
    width: auto;
```

with `auto` your image not be stretched wrong.

## previous code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
}

.container .image {
  height: 50vh;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="image" src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest CSS tools are sufficient. So your topbar is 46px in height which means your images should reside on top of each other in a full viewport (100vh) but less 46 px. Lets share that 46px among images 23px each.

```css
#topbar {
  background: maroon;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 46px;
  width: 100vw;
  }
#mg {
  display: block;
  height: calc(50vh - 23px);
  }
#jl {
  height: calc(50vh - 23px);
  }
```

```html
<div id="topbar">Hi..! I am the topbar with a 46px height.</div>
<image id="mg" src="https://www.gazetemag.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Mel-Gibson-1.jpg">
<image id="jl" src="https://i.tmgrup.com.tr/vogue/img/photo_gallery_b/18-08/15/jennifer-lopez-955778686.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's an easier method for me to understand!