# I gave class "img-fluid" to my image but it doesn’t fit the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I gave my image class "img-fluid" in Bootstrap but it doesn’t fit my web page what should I do?

```
    <img src="images\406201.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
    <div style="margin-top: 0px ;margin-left: 12px; width: 98.4%;" class="footer bg-dark text-light p-5">
        <h3 style="text-align: center;">follow Us</h3>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
            <a href="#"><img style="width: 65px; margin: 2px;border-radius: 5px;" src="images/facebook-logo.png"
                    class="bg-light" alt="..."></a>
            <a href="#"><img style="width: 65px; margin: 2px;border-radius: 5px;" src="images\twitter-logo.png"
                    class="bg-light" alt="..."></a>
            <a href="#"><img style="width: 65px; margin: 2px;border-radius: 5px;"
                    src="images\instagram-logo-png-transparent-0.png" class="bg-light" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img style="width: 65px; margin: 2px;border-radius: 5px;"
                    src="images\telegram-logo-png-0.png" class="bg-light" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <h4 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 15px;">Powered by Marvel Studious</h4>
    </div>
```

When I give it style="width=100%" it works but the problem is it doesn’t need CSS.

Comment: Put a more complete code. Bootstrap classes are highly dependent on their parents

Comment: Inspect Element - Play with the CSS rules. Than when you cannot fix it explain: 1: What have you tried, 2: what is needed, 3: what it actually does

Comment: if you want fit your image please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14696457/1075028).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but `img-fluid` puts the image in the maximum size possible given where it is, for example, if it is inside a `div`, the image will be the size of the div and not the screen, so make sure you don't have the image inside something that is limiting its size

Comment: yeah I didn’t put the img tag in other tag like div You can see my code obviously, my first pic just exactly fitted my web screen but this one didn’t

Comment: sorry, but the code you posted above works for me (at least I think this is what you want)
[image](https://ibb.co/72MhBnV) (ignore the random images I have used)

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in a div with class "container-fluid".

```
<style>
    .width-complete{
        width:100%
    }
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="images\406201.jpg" class="width-complete" alt="...">
</div>
```